# Qt bug where container resize at run time

Tags: c++, qt

I have a nasty bug where the size of my container(s) / layout(s) resize themselves whenever I click on a text box. When the resize occurs, all of the widgets are re-aligned to what they should be in the designer (I created the layout and the interface using the designer). I thought that if I were to force the interface to redraw itself when displayed, the containers would resize but this did not work. I have been looking on the net to see if there is anything similar and so far, there is nothing. I have pictures and a minimal-ish code example prepared.

I am running linux mint 19.1 with Qt 5.9 (the version that comes with my distro).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Before the resize:

[image: Before resize happens]

After the resize:

[image: After resize happens]

Also, here is the code example. I apologize for the length of this one but this is literally the smallest that I could get:

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>448</width>
    <height>709</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
    <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    <weight>50</weight>
    <italic>false</italic>
    <bold>false</bold>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>431</width>
      <height>621</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_9">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Access Control</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>401</width>
        <height>561</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_7">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Misc. Options</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_5">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>571</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
       <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_5">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>444</width>
         <height>608</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_12">
          <property name="sizeConstraint">
           <enum>QLayout::SetMaximumSize</enum>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_241">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>443</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>BEEPER OPTIONS</string>
            </property>
            <property name="alignment">
             <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_262">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>341</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>This is a checkbox that is being used to </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="verticalSpacer_10">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeType">
           <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>10</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_13">
          <property name="sizeConstraint">
           <enum>QLayout::SetMaximumSize</enum>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_242">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>443</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>DRYCYCLE CONTROLS</string>
            </property>
            <property name="alignment">
             <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_273">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_274">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="verticalSpacer_11">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeType">
           <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>10</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_14">
          <property name="sizeConstraint">
           <enum>QLayout::SetMaximumSize</enum>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_243">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>443</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Operation Bypass Controls</string>
            </property>
            <property name="alignment">
             <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_275">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>341</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_276">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_277">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_278">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_279">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>443</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Option</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="simulateSortingCheckBox">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>34</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Another text that is really long in order</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_12">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_7">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeType">
               <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QCheckBox" name="randomSortCheckBox">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>0</width>
                <height>34</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Sub option 1</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_13">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_8">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeType">
               <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QCheckBox" name="sequentialSortCheckBox">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>0</width>
                <height>34</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Sub option 2</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_14">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_9">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeType">
               <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QCheckBox" name="fixedSortCheckBox">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Sub option 3</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLineEdit" name="Fixed_Sort_to_bin">
              <property name="text">
               <string>8</string>
              </property>
              <property name="readOnly">
               <bool>true</bool>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_10">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeType">
               <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>110</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>448</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFont>

#define SELECTED_CHECK_BOX "QCheckBox {border: 2px solid gray;}"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QWidget *p_previouseSelectedWidget = nullptr;

    QFont p_setFont;

public slots:
    void handleFocusChange(QWidget *oldWidget, QWidget *newWidget);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    p_setFont = this->font();

    connect(qApp, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)), this, SLOT(handleFocusChange(QWidget*,QWidget*)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::handleFocusChange(QWidget *oldWidget, QWidget *newWidget)
{
    if(!this->isHidden())
    {
        if(!dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(newWidget))
        {
            if(p_previouseSelectedWidget)
            {
                p_previouseSelectedWidget->setStyleSheet("");
                p_previouseSelectedWidget->setFont(p_setFont);
            }

             p_previouseSelectedWidget = newWidget;
        }

        if(dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(newWidget))
        {
            // Do some stuff
            newWidget->setStyleSheet(SELECTED_CHECK_BOX);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Edit:

I am now sharing the mainWindow.ui.

Comment: *" I apologize for the length of this one but this is literally the smallest that I could get"* This looks like all of the code, it doesn't appear to have been minimized in any way. Maybe you need to make a new project that isolates the problem and share that instead. Please read about [MCVE]s.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for posting a link for the resource. However, this is the smallest code that I could produce for the bug to appear. This is two tabs from an interface that has this bug. I replaced all of the text for confidential purposes. The bug appears with 2+ tabs. I wanted to keep the overall layout of that form the same as what I have in the actual program. There are 4 files because I created the interface in the designer.

Comment: You can start by removing all of the options, then the tabs, and continue to remove elements until you find those that, when removed, eliminate the problem. Continue until there is nothing non-essential left to remove. You may very well find the answer yourself. Even if you don't knowing which elements are actually part of the problem provide valuable clues. This will also result in a smaller code to debug. If absolutely everything here is essential to reproducing the problem, it's unlikely anyone will take the time to try to track down the cause for you.

Comment: OK, I have edited my code sample and I was able to remove some widgets for the bug to still appear. In the Dycycle Controls layout and Operation Bypass Controls, if you remove any widget, the bug does not appear. If you remove any layout widget, the bug no longer appears. So the code is now the smallest that I could get it. I know that it is a little cumbersome but it is the best that I can do.

Comment: @philm share `mainwindow.ui` instead `ui_mainwindow.h`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated my post to match accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Basically, in the `scrollAreaWidgetContents` container, I changed the `layoutSizeContraint` from the default value to `SetMinandMaxSize`.

I have tried this on a number of my forms and the window is not longer displaying the behaviour posted above.